# Insert a file into multer req.files

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, multer

I want to insert a file from elsewhere into a req object as it could be generated by multer from a real request.

I've got my file content into a variable (I could also save it somewhere, on a tmp folder, if necessary).

And I want to create from it that kind of object, that can usually be found in one of the req.files generated by multer :

```
{ fieldname: ...,
  originalname: ...,
  name: ...,
  encoding: ...,
  mimetype: ...,
  path: ...,
  extension: ...,
  size: ...,
  truncated: ...,
  buffer: ... }
```

Because I must send it to a middleware that expects that...

Probably I could create this object property by property but I would be long & boring for some of these.

So I was wondering if something can do it for me (maybe an express pluggin or a function I missed ?). Thanks !

Edit : woops, seems it is generated by Multer, not express directly. I edited.